# Change SQL statement upon change on seclection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sql-server

I have two `divs`.

**First `div`**

Has `inputs` like `checkbox` and `select`.

```
<div>Events Selection</div>
Events <input type="checkbox" id="Option-1" checked="true">
Leaves <input type="checkbox" id="Option-2" checked="true">
Meetings <input type="checkbox" id="Option-3" checked="true">
Travels <input type="checkbox" id="Option-4" checked="true">

<div>Station Selection</div>           
<select id="Filters1">
<option value="0">All Stations</option>
<option value="1">Main Station</option>
<option value="2">Sub Station</option>
<option value="3">Sub Station Main Office</option>
</select>
```

**Second `div`**

Has a SQL statement `$sql = "SELECT * FROM events";` which i want to echo all those checked and selected options from `First div`.

So, my question is how to dynamically change the SQL statement when the selections or checkbox changed in `First div`.

Like: When the page loads, it should be like this:

```
$sql = Select * From events Where (every checkboxes are 
checked and `All Stations` are selected.)
```

and when a user wants to filter the result from `First div` then the `$sql` statement should be changed to what the user selected and checked.

Like: I want to check the `Events` and `Meetings` checkbox with `Main Station` selection, so now i want that the `$sql` statement should be change to my selection in the `Second div`.

Comment: Use ajax to send the post items then your where statement should be foreach post_name = post_value

Comment: Thanks for your comment dear @SamirNabil, but i am in bad luck :) because i am in second semester and not an expert at this. I can fetch data from MySQL but can't change the `$sql` statement upon change, and if you guide me through then i would be glad. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

At first use parameterized query's, don't construct them dynamically. Examples and explanation on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296201(v=sql.105).aspx).

Write stored procedure that will receive `value` of selected option and will bring you data you need. F.e.:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.getevents
    @value int
AS
SELECT * 
FROM events
WHERE somecolumn = @value
```

It is simplified version, I guess you need some `if` statement like `IF @value = 0...SELECT this ... IF @value = 1`

In that case you can use:

```
$sql = "EXEC dbo.getevents ?";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array($value));
```

And then fetch results and show it on your page.

**EDIT#1**

**Using XAMP and SQL Server 2014**

Disclaimer: I post this code only for demonstration purpose. Parameters are passed as a string, no styling, maybe some mistakes.

I have an installed **XAMP**. Downloaded `sqlsrv` libraries, enable them in `php.ini`.

I got local SQL Server with database `Test`. SQL server has an instance named `sqldev`. My computer name is `workshop`. So, instead of `SERVER\INSTANCE` should be `workshop\sqldev`. Instead of `DATABASE` - `Test`. That is what I wrote to connect.

At first I create table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dummy (
    id int identity(1,1),
    [Desc] nvarchar(max),
    [Type] nvarchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO dummy VALUES
('Do something already','Events'),
('Congrats!','Events'),
('Meet up at six PM','Meetings'),
('To Amsterdam','Travels'),
('goodbye!','Leaves')
```

Table contains some dummy-data to play with.

The next step:

Download **jQuery** from https://jquery.com/download/ (I used `jquery-3.1.1.js`)

*index.php*

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <style>
        table {
            width:20%
        }
        table, td, th {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: 1px solid gray;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Events Selection</div>
    Events <input type="checkbox" id="option" class="options" name="options[]" value="Events"> 
    Leaves <input type="checkbox" id="option"  class="options" name="options[]" value="Leaves">
    Meetings <input type="checkbox" id="option" class="options" name="options[]" value="Meetings">
    Travels <input type="checkbox" id="option" class="options" name="options[]" value="Travels">
    <div id="response"></div>

    <script>

    $('input:checkbox').click(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "sql_page.php",
        type: "post",
        data: $('.options:checked').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
        $('#response').html(data);
        }
    });

    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

*sql_page.php*

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$serverName = "SERVER\INSTANCE";
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"DATABASE");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if(isset($_POST['options'])) {

    if( $conn === false ) {
        echo "Unable to connect.</br>";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    $values = $_POST['options'];
    $valuelist = "'" . implode("', '", $values) . "'";
    $tsql = "SELECT * FROM dummy WHERE [Type] IN (".$valuelist.");";

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);

    if( $stmt === false ) {
        echo "Error in executing query.</br>";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    echo "<table>";
    while ($obj = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) {
    echo "<tr>
            <td>".$obj[0]."</td>
            <td>".$obj[1]."</td>
            <td>".$obj[2]."</td>
        </tr>\n";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
    sqlsrv_close( $conn );
}
?>
```

Then I go on `index.php` in my browser:

[image: how it works]

If you are using MySQL you need another libraries and commands to use, but they are similar to what I wrote. The main idea is to connect to the  database and run some query with parameters, it is a `sql_page.php` idea.

The `index.php` part sends Ajax request to `sql_page.php` when checkboxes are clicked. And then show the data from this page (that was got from SQL Server) in div with `id=response`.

**EDIT#2**

**Using EasyPHP Devserver 16.1.1** dowloaded from [here](http://www.easyphp.org/save-easyphp-devserver-latest.php?d=direct)

I installed *EasyPHP* in default folder, start it, went to `http://127.0.0.1:1111`, started Apache + PHP on port `8888`, started MySQL.

I create a DB named `air-hr`, table named `events` in it. The script and structure of table below:

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `eventid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `eventname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `eventcategory` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `events` (`eventid`, `eventname`, `eventcategory`) VALUES
(1, 'Go now!', 'Leaves'),
(2, 'Meet some new people', 'Meetings'),
(3, 'Travel to Amsterdam', 'Travels'),
(4, 'PARTY HARD!', 'Events');
```

Also I create user `test` that can connect to DB and select from table.

I have created 2 files in `C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www` project folder (their description is below) and copy `jquery-3.1.1.js`.

*index.php* like above and

*sql_page.php*

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

if(isset($_POST['options'])) {

    $values = $_POST['options'];
    $valuelist = "'" . implode("', '", $values) . "'";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE eventcategory IN (".$valuelist.");";

    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "test", "testpass", "air-hr");
    if (!$link) {
        echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
        exit;
    }

    echo "<table>";
    if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
            echo "<tr>
                <td>".$row[0]."</td>
                <td>".$row[1]."</td>
                <td>".$row[2]."</td>
            </tr>\n";
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
    echo "</table>";

    mysqli_close($link);
}

?>
```

And results here:

[image: easyphp]

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i am at second semester, so it is a bit difficult for me to get. Can you please explain how, a bit. I mean i have the form and divs. How can i actually connect the filters and `$sql` statement.

Comment: i have a connected database with `$conn` and it works fine with static `$sql` statement but don't work with dynamic `$sql` statement like the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot @gofr1, i would be glad. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i tried two hours to figure out why it is not working with me and still i don't know.
I didn't get it that where is the host, database name, table name, and if you sit then where is it because it doesn't work.......

Comment: I have already assigned a connection to my database with `$conn` and it works fine. just tell me how to get data from `air-hr` database and `events` table.

Comment: Dear gofr1. I am using `easyphp`, it has MySQL database and php installed already. I just don't know where to connect. My host is `127.0.0.1` and my database name is `air-hr` and table is `events` inside `events` i have `eventid`, `eventname` and `eventcategory`, so how should i integrate it based on my information.

Comment: I deleted all my comments, part of them I add to the answer. In EDIT#2 there is an example of using EasyPHP.

Comment: Thanks a lot gofr1 it works awesome and i appreciate your hard work :). Can you please also embed the dropdowns too - as i asked in the question. Thanks again.

Comment: I already spend much time on this answer and I suggest you to implement  solution with dropdown by yourself. :) It is much easier than with checkboxes, because there will be only one more value to post. Or you can go another way and filter already fetched results with jQuery. ;) I prefer second way.

Comment: F.e. you can use this http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Simple-jQuery-Dropdown-Table-Filter-Plugin-ddtf-js.html plug-in

Comment: I know you spend your time and I appreciate that heartily, but I am at the basic stages of coding. Ok I will try to find a solution, let me do some search, ahahahah, I don't know what the result will be but I will do, thanks, but still I need your wise solutions. :)

Answer (score 0):

here you code

first named your inputs and select as follow:

```
<form action="sql_page.php" method="post">
 <div>Events Selection</div>
   Events <input type="checkbox" id="Option-1" name="Option-1" checked="true">
   Leaves <input type="checkbox" id="Option-2" name="Option-2" checked="true">
   Meetings <input type="checkbox" id="Option-3" name="Option-3" checked="true">
   Travels <input type="checkbox" id="Option-4" name="Option-4" checked="true">

 <div>Station Selection</div>           
  <select id="Filters1" name="Filters1">
  <option value="0">All Stations</option>
  <option value="1">Main Station</option>
  <option value="2">Sub Station</option>
  <option value="3">Sub Station Main Office</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

and in your sql_page.php here php code

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
foreach ($_POST as $col => $value) {

    $whare .= "$col = '$value' AND ";
}
$whare = rtrim($whare,'AND ');


$sql = "Select * From events Where $whare";


}
```

Comment: Thanks @Samir. I have and error `Undefined variable: whare`

Comment: add before foreach `$where = ''` but is give your right sql statement?

Comment: Sorry i couldn't get it. Can you fix it in your answer. Thanks.

Comment: `if (isset($_POST)) {
$where=''; foreach ($_POST as $col => $value) {

    $whare .= "$col = '$value' AND ";
}
$whare = rtrim($whare,'AND ');


$sql = "Select * From events Where $whare";


}`

Comment: Again `Undefined variable: whare`

Comment: also i want that `First div` and `sql_page.php` should be in the same page.